# Perturbation theory for an asymmetric top

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am working through Prof. Littlejohn's [notes](https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/notes/pertth.pdf) on perturbation theory, and I'm trying exercise number 2, which asks to analyze an asymmetric top. (The exact problem statement is in the notes.) I'm confused about what Littlejohn means by the perturbation on the $m=0$, $m=\pm1$, and $m=\pm2$ states. Specifying $m$ doesn't give a unique eigenstate of $L_z$. Am I to observe the perturbation of a specific eigenstate $|{lm}\rangle$? For instance, if I want to see the perturbation of $|l\,0\rangle$, first order shift in the eigenstate will be
$$|l\,0\rangle +\lambda \sum_{l'\neq l}\sum_{m'\neq 0}\frac{C\langle{l'm'}|L_+^2+L_-^2|l'\,0\rangle}{E_{l0}-E_{l'm'}} |l'm'\rangle,$$
and I don't have to worry about degeneracies since $E_{l\,0}$ is nondegenerate for all $l$. Am I on the right track? I guess we can narrow down the terms a lot since $m'\neq \pm2$ terms will vanish. But the resulting summation still seems nasty over $l$. It could be just a misinterpretation of the question, but I have no clue what he's asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need only $l^{\prime} = l$, since the angular momentum does not mix together subspaces with different values of $l$?